# How do I bake relative dates into a data set in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report that will always show yesterday's numbers but the SSRS documentation is weak on examples in this area.  **Yesterday** is one of the relative date values for use as filter criteria - but where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden parameter on the report, which is given a default value of:

```
dateadd("d",-1,today())
```